# ViewPager child element affecting parent LinearLayout (bad bottom alignment)

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-viewpager, android-linearlayout

I have detected a layout consistency issue between 2 layouts, when using a ViewPager with Tabs navigation on one of them. I have the following 2 very similar XML layout for a FragmentActivity (that uses the viewpager) and another for a normal activity:

**FragmentActivity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

    <package.ui.tabs.CustomViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.84"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    </package.ui.tabs.CustomViewPager>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_menu_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

    <!-- ...other stuff... -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**(Normal) Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.84">

    <!-- ...other stuff... -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_menu_bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

    <!-- ...other stuff... -->

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Nota that the CustomViewPager is the ViewPager implementation that the SDK provides by creating a new TabsActivity eclipse project. I'll add the code below just so you can be assured the view positioning and measuring is not being overridden in any way:

**CustomViewPager.java**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Even though they are **completely equal on base layout formatting**, as they have same weight properties and use the same type of layouts, these two activities are **different on both the Eclipse WYSIWYG and at run-time by one pixel at the bottom of the screen** - the FragmentActivity will not align the last LinearLayout to bottom, even when forced to with 0 margin properties, while the normal activity behaves as expected. The result is something like the picture in the link below (I have no reputation for pictures):

[Layout error](http://postimage.org/image/pfzd9v5rb/)

So all in all, using the viewpager produces the unexpected bad alignment with the screen bottom. I initially used a root RelativeLayout to contain the viewpager and the LinearLayout and margins were OK, aligning with the bottom even with a viewpager.

The problem is that I need this as a LinearLayout in order to proportionally scale the 2 children using weight, so that I **avoid**:

1. Using absolute dip heights;
2. creating multiple layout files for different screen densities;
3. changing layout behaviour programatically and on runtime to solve layout issues.

The question then is how to prevent this inconsistency using a ViewPager so that I can have a static LinearLayout in my app, with a bottom static bar, that does not change when I switch activities?

Comment: Why does it say 0.84 on the first and 0.86 on the second?

Comment: Because I edited it wrong while adapting the question attached code to be more generic, without other app context-specific issues that have no effect on layout. The question still applies as this is not the cause - in the layout with the ViewPager, the weightSum is 1, the 2 children have 0.86+0.14=1 layout_weight and I still get a 1dip/pixel wide margin at the bottom, which is affecting the "navigational" consistency between supposedly static elements in both this layout and other layouts. But yeah, that also would affect my final purpose. I have edited the question with the correct values.